# Is this some kind of triangle inquality?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, triangles

I stumbled upon the following inequality:

$$\Vert x+hz-(x+y)-(p-(x+y))\Vert_2 \geq \Vert p-(x+y)\Vert_2-\Vert x+hz-(x+y)\Vert_2$$

where $p,x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

My question is: *Is this some kind of simple triangle inequality?*

Because to me, it totally looks like that but I can't figure it out, any approach ended up with something like a $+$ instead of a $-$ or a $\leq$ instead of a $\geq$. I need to know if the author is using a rather simple trick with the norms (aka. triangle inequality) or if there's more about it.

I (once again) feel like I'm missing out on something completely obvious, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's just the triangle inequality. Note that $\lVert a-b\rVert = \lVert b-a\rVert$, and your inequality is $\lVert a-b\rVert \geqslant \lVert b\rVert - \lVert a\rVert$. Reducing that to the standard form is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a second form of triangle inequality :

$|a-b| \geq ||a|-|b||$ and in particular $|a-b| \geq |a|-|b|$

On simple example (let's say we are in the 2-dimensionnal euclidian space), you can understand it as follows : when substracting two vectors, you can see that the "smallest" vector you can achieve is by taking $a$ and $b$ positively related ($a=\lambda b,\lambda \geq 0$), in which case the norm $||a-b||$ is exactly $||a||-||b||$ (or $||b||-||a||$ if $\lambda \leq 1$). Otherwise, it is greater than that.

Proof : let $|.|$ be a norm, $u,v$ two elements, then

$|u|=|u-v+v| \leq |u-v| + |v|$ hence $|u| - |v| \leq |u-v|$. You can do the same swapping $u$ and $v$ to get the other way around, and finally get the inequality for the absolute value.

Comment: I know the reverse triangle inequality, but for some reason I didn't see what you showed in 2nd line. I'm deeply ashamed and thankful!

Answer (score 1):

Move the second term in the RHS to the LHS. Now rewrite teh LHS by switching which term is negative. Then use the triangle inequality.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although your instructions were not that precise, this also did the trick for me. The accepted answer just made it even more easy to see for me. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of the reverse triangle inequality
$$|\|a\| - \|b\|| \le \|a + b\|,$$
which follows from the triangle inequality for any norm.

By triangle inequality
$$\|a\| - \|b\| \le \|a + b\|,$$
$$\|b\| - \|a\| \le \|a + b\|.$$
Therefore
$$|\|a\| - \|b\|| \le \|a + b\|.$$

Comment: Thanks! This should already be enough for anybody with a similar question (and the slightest bit of brains), but I was too blind to see what "special case" you (and the author) meant. Sorry.

Comment: @Piwi: The special case here is simply one of the two inequalities (which don't have absolute values) used to derive the reverse triangle inequality. Indeed: If $|x| \le something$, then both $x \le something$ and $-x \le something$.